# WS-I Basic Profile 2.0 compliant frameworks

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, apache-axis, ws-i

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile) a number of WS-I Basic Profile (BP) compliant frameworks are listed. However, it is not clear to which version of the BP the framework is compliant to. So my question is as follows:

**Which frameworks/products (Java, .NET and others) are compliant to WS-I Basic Profile 2.0?**

The answer of this question may be of interest in the selection of an enterprise web service standard. It seems as if most frameworks are compliant to BP 1.1, but the question is whether the IT environments are ready to be upgraded to BP 2.0 (including MTOM binary attachments, WS-Addressing, SOAP 1.2 and UDDI 3.

Studying one **example** framework, the IBM WebSphere Message Broker (WMB), more closely I found the following information:

- [the platform supports WS-I Basic Profile Version 1.1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac55700_.htm)
- the platform supports e.g. WS-Addressing and SOAP 1.2
- by using the HTTP proxy servlet pattern you indirectly get the same support as given by the Java EE application server

However, I did not find any explicit statement detailing that the product supports WS-I Basic Profile Version 2.0. *The same seems to be the case for many frameworks...*